# Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/style.css is not exported from package

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a public lib build by vite, now I want to import the css from the public lib:

```
import 'rd-component/dist/style.css';
```

but when I build the project, shows error:

```
ERROR in ./src/page/photo/gen/GenPhoto.tsx 18:0-37
Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/style.css is not exported from package /Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/rd-component (see exports field in /Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/rd-component/package.json)

webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
No issues found.
```

what should I do to export the css file? I have tried like this:

```
plugins: [
    {
      name: 'extract-css', 
      generateBundle(_, bundle) {
        for (const fileName in bundle) {
          const chunk = bundle[fileName];

          if (fileName.endsWith('.js') && chunk.code.includes('import "./style.css";')) {
            const cssFileName = fileName.replace('.js', '.css');
            const css = chunk.code.match(/(?<=import ")[^"]+(?=";)/s)[0];

            fs.writeFileSync(`dist/${cssFileName}`, css, 'utf-8');

            chunk.code = chunk.code.replace(css, `./${cssFileName}`);
          }
        }
      },
    },
  ],
```

shows error that chunk did not contains code attribute. how to export the css from public lib and import from currrent project successfully? this is the `node_modules` of public lib:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found I have to export the css like this in `package.json`:

```
"exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js"
        },
        "./dist/style.css": {
            "import": "./dist/style.css",
            "require": "./dist/style.css"
        }
    },
```

more information from here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/2657